# Multiple clicks on slideToggle - stop() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to build expandable blocks with jQuery's `slideToggle()`. My code is nothing special:

```
$('.main-blocks').on('click', 'article.expand a', function() {            
    var article = $(this).closest('article'),
        scroll = article.offset().top;

    article.children('.desc').stop().slideToggle('fast', function() {
        Functions.masonryBlocks(scroll);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Can't be more simple. But, when I click multiple times on a target link, block is *bouncing*, like there isn't any `stop()` - and there is one.

What can I do with this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n8har5nb/1/ (thanks to @Arun P Johny)

Comment: Doesn't help either, I even tried `stop(true, true)`.

Comment: can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? it is strange that `.stop()` does not work for you, can you recreate the issue in a fiddle so we can see?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n8har5nb/1/

Comment: seems to work in Aruns fiddle

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny, the code is the same. It's bouncing. I am on Ubuntu 13 (FF and Chrome), perhaps that's the case?

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery 1.11.1 pulled from code.jquery.com.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski So that's not your issue

Comment: do you have another code block somewhere that might be interfering with the `.stop()` ?

Comment: @TomekBuszewski whether the fiddle is working for you

Comment: @Banana No, it's the only written function.

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's bouncing, just like in mine problem.

Comment: its hard to believe that the issue is related to your OS, as javascript is being executed by the browser and the two most advanced browsers out there would not screw up like this. maybe you have partial javascript disabled in the browser settings?

Comment: @banana: Firefox is vanilla, Chrome has couple of plugins, but nothing niche or suspicious. It's extra weird, since I use `stop().slideToggle` all the time and it's the first time I see this.

Comment: can you download a different browser just for testing purposes? some opera or dolfin, just to see if the issue persists

Comment: I can't, it's not mine. I'll see in home if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery `.stop()` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/stop/
The method has two optional params: `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd`, you could make use of them.